# Building Android library project with external file

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I have an Android library project (Properties > Android > IsLibrary checked) that pulls in an external file (C++ shared library), and packages it along with all the class files into a jar.  With Eclipse, everything works fine, but with ant, the jar file only contains class files and not the shared library.  Is there a way to modify build.xml to include the external file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is apparently to create ant.properties with paths to both Java source, and C++ library:

```
source.dir=src:path-to-dir
```

However, this doesn't work in the current Android SDK, and the workaround is to modify build.xml by adding the following:

```
<target name="-pre-clean">
    <delete dir="tmp" />
</target>
<target name="-pre-build">
    <copy todir="tmp">
        <fileset dir="path-to-dir" includes="**" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="tmp">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

and create ant.properties with:

```
source.dir=tmp
```